# pandas ols import broken?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to do OLS in pandas 0.9.1 but get this error:

```
ipdb> foo = ols(y=df[y_var[1]], x=df[x_var], pool=False )
*** ImportError: No module named scikits.statsmodels.api
```

I guess the error comes from ols.py:

```
try:
    import statsmodels.api as sm
except ImportError:
    import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
```

Does this mean I've installed pandas incorrectly?

Comment: [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net) is a separate package that is an optional dependency for pandas.  You'll need to install statsmodels to do OLS.  Try `pip install statsmodels`.  You'll probably want to install the development build.  I think they're close to releasing a new version so it should be very stable.

Comment: just cross tagging Peter and Tom in case you know the answer to my problem (and to help out fellow people in the same boat..) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454229/ols-import-broken-in-pandas-easy-install-finds-the-right-package-but-fails-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TomAugspurger to the rescue:

> statsmodels is a separate package that is an optional dependency for
>   pandas. You'll need to install statsmodels to do OLS. Try pip install
>   statsmodels. You'll probably want to install the development build. I
>   think they're close to releasing a new version so it should be very
>   stable. – TomAugspurger 2 hours