# OLS import broken in Pandas; easy_install finds the right package but fails for some reason

Tags: python, pandas, pip, easy-install, statsmodels

this may be a followup question from [pandas ols import broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836137/pandas-ols-import-broken)

I am on Python 2.7 and have the exact same issue but do not have the same success as Peter in resolving.

The main problem is the stable version of statsmodels is 0.6.1. (per http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/). Pandas uses the OLS function from statsmodels.api which is only available in the development version 0.7.0. I find it hard to believe that after 2 (or more, if some of my search results are to be believed!) years pandas is still broken?

@TomAugspurger suggested `!pip install statsmodels` (im doing this within ipython). with that I get:

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): statsmodels in c:\users\swang\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages
>
> Cleaning up...

so `!pip install --upgrade statsmodels` then gets me

> Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ Could not
>   find any downloads that satisfy the requirement statsmodels in
>   c:\users\swang\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages
>   Downloading/unpacking statsmodels Cleaning up... No distributions at
>   all found for statsmodels in
>   c:\users\swang\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages
>   Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\swang\pip\pip.log

Despite statsmodels being clearly visible in https://pypi.python.org/simple/.

`!easy_install -U statsmodels` gives the most promising result:

> Searching for statsmodels Reading
>   http://pypi.python.org/simple/statsmodels/ Reading
>   http://pypi.python.org/simple/statsmodels/ Couldn't retrieve index
>   page for 'statsmodels' Scanning index of all packages (this may take a
>   while) Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/ **Best match: statsmodels
>   0.7.0 Adding statsmodels 0.7.0 to easy-install.pth file**
>
> Using
>   c:\users\swang\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages
>   Processing dependencies for statsmodels Finished processing
>   dependencies for statsmodels Download error on
>   http://pypi.python.org/simple/statsmodels/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507:
>   error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol --
>   Some packages may not be found! Download error on
>   http://pypi.python.org/simple/statsmodels/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507:
>   error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol --
>   Some packages may not be found! Download error on
>   http://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507:
>   error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol --
>   Some packages may not be found!

Yes!!! 0.7.0! give me that! why is server not saying hello?

I have also tried `!easy_install -U scikits.statsmodels` and many other variations, without success.

**Bottomline/TL;DR** - I need to upgrade my statsmodels to 0.7.0 and `pip install --upgrade` and `easy_install -U` won't let me. I think easy_install -U gets me closest to the goal but fails there and I cannot figure out why. I don't think I'm technically able enough to compile the raw code from https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/. Could you please advise the best way for a newbie to fix this one simple problem?

Comment: re: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577947/pip-install-pandas-couldnt-find-any-downloads-that-satisfy-the-requirement-pand yes, pinging the server works so its not that.

Comment: pip list says i currently have pip (1.5.6), pandas (0.14.0) and statsmodels (0.6.1) if that helps...

Comment: Why do you try to use `easy_install` if you already have `pip` available? `pip` is much more powerful and occurring errors are often much easier to debug. I would try `pip install -U scikits.statsmodels` and see if that works.

Comment: my issue was solved with the binaries per Burhan's link below; but still keen on learning how to actually use pip properly. so @cel for reference, i did try that, and this is what i got:


Downloading/unpacking scikits.statsmodels

  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/

  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement scikits.statsmodels

Cleaning up...

No distributions at all found for scikits.statsmodels

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\swang\pip\pip.log - sorry for the jumble as i cant figure out how to format comments properly

Comment: i also tried `!pip install -U scikits.statsmodels --index-url https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.statsmodels` with no success ("Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.statsmodels/" - and i can ping that fine) i dont understand why it's not working - would be very very useful for future problems if you have any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no release available with 0.7.0; which is why you cannot install it from `pip`.

You can visit the [PyPi page for the module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels/) to find out what are all the *published releases*.

To solve the problem, you can install the development trunk. Thankfully the group releases [windows binaries](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/binaries/) and you can find one compatible with your version of Python.

Comment: oh god the binaries. life saver! thanks. found it on the 0.6.1 but not the 0.7.0. i guess this means i wont know how to properly manipulate pip... but im glad to move on after being stuck here for 4 hours. thanks again.